# Troubleshooting Out of memory error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I concatenate two vectors of length 20,000,000 in MATLAB?

> x=randn(1,20000000);
>
> y=x;
>
> z=[x y];
>
> w=[x y];

when I enter w = [x y]; it errors out :

> Error using horzcat
>   Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

```
    >> [uV sV] = memory

    uV = 

        MaxPossibleArrayBytes: 710127616
        MemAvailableAllArrays: 1.6797e+009
                MemUsedMATLAB: 345354240


    sV = 

        VirtualAddressSpace: [1x1 struct]
               SystemMemory: [1x1 struct]
             PhysicalMemory: [1x1 struct]

    >> sV.VirtualAddressSpace

    ans = 

        Available: 1.6797e+009
            Total: 2.1474e+009

    >> sV.SystemMemory

    ans = 

        Available: 4.4288e+009

    >> sV.PhysicalMemory

    ans = 

        Available: 2.5376e+009
            Total: 3.4889e+009
```

Comment: did you try `HELP MEMORY`?

Comment: How much RAM do you have, and do you have 64 bit or 32 bit matlab? And is it correct to assume that except for the two variables your memory is cleared?

Comment: Please paste the output of `memory`, before/after a failed concatenation.

Comment: >> [uV sV] = memory
uV = 
MaxPossibleArrayBytes: 710127616
MemAvailableAllArrays: 1.6797e+009
                    MemUsedMATLAB: 345354240
sV = 
            VirtualAddressSpace: [1x1 struct]
                   SystemMemory: [1x1 struct]
                 PhysicalMemory: [1x1 struct]
        >> sV.VirtualAddressSpace
        ans = 
            Available: 1.6797e+009
                Total: 2.1474e+009
        >> sV.SystemMemory
        ans = 
            Available: 4.4288e+009
       >> sV.PhysicalMemory
        ans = 
             Available: 2.5376e+009
                Total: 3.4889e+009

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin 4 GB, 32 bit.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: You ran out of address space. For such large data, 64bit Matlab and 64bit OS is the only practical solution.

Comment: @DanielR In this case changing the datatype should do the trick, but then it is indeed a matter of time before you run into the next constraint.

Answer (score 1):

This [document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html) explains how to resolve the error. The reason for the error is mostly due to the memory constraint of the machine rather than MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how one typically would do it efficiently:

```
x = ones(20000000,1);
y = x;
z1 = [x y];
z2 = [x; y];
```

The first is for horizontal concatenation, the second for vertical.
This does not generate any errors for me, even if I make the variable 10x bigger.

If you cannot run the first three lines, you seem to have insufficient memory to store 4x20000000 numbers. You can try whether you have enough memory to store 3x20000000 numbers and use this instead:

```
x = [x y];
```

If the error does not occur with my exaple, then you are probably doing something wrong, please show code that reproduces the error then.

Comment: Here is the code:
x=randn(1,20000000);
y=x;
z=[x y];
w=[x y];

the error happens when I enter w=[x y];

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi I believe you exceed the maximum variable size for your 32 bit matlab. You cannot increase this, but perhaps using the `single` datatype is sufficient for you? Try starting with `x=single(randn(1,20000000));`

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do, either there's enough memory or not.

A single 20.000.000 elements double vector takes up 320MB. That makes 640MB for the concatenated version.
If your concatenation is like `c = [a,b]` this will sum up to 1.28 GB (cause you'll have `a`, `b` and `c`).
Whether 1.28GB is "much", depends on your machine.

If your machine physically has enough memory you should try clearing eventually existing other large matrices in matlab or even close other applications.

Last but not least:
If your vectors contain a lot of zeros, you should check `sparse` matrices.
They only store non-zero elements and hence might take up much less memory.

Comment: If these memory requirements are correct, it is not likely that the computer will really run out of memory. Perhaps the maximum array size is hit?

Comment: Sure they are correct, why should they not? It's simply 8 byte per number. Why isn't likely in this case? I'm writing this on a somewhat old macbook, with 3GB ram, no MATLAB running at all and there's less than 1.3GB memory free. An as an aside: Matlab needs adjacent memory for each individual array, so you might run into this issue even if in total there's enough memory left.

Comment: I believe that matlab will typically not give an error when it runs out of RAM. Instead it will just go for the painfully slow option to store data out of RAM. This is why I would be surprised to see a computer run out of memory under 1.3 GB. I didn't find a good source for this but perhaps you could give it a quick try?

Answer (score 1):

A general answer can be found in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html). If this does not resolve your problem, add your code to the question. Maybe preallocation or something else can solve the memory issues.

Comment: Based on the given example memory output it points towards the maximum size for 1 array. In that case the method of concatenation won't make a difference.